# using output of a function as a string variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to use output of my function as a string variable.

I have this function:

```
schemaTitle: function() {
    return Categories.findOne({_id: "Gt5prgS4RW3GW23NG"}).title;
}
```

now I want to use output of above **return** like a string variable, somewhere like this:

```
switch(this.schemaTitle) {
    case "HOME":
        return {
            schemaName: "StateSchema"
        };
        break; 
}
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not invoking the function `schemaTitle`, only referencing it. Just replace

```
switch(this.schemaTitle) {
```

with

```
switch(this.schemaTitle()) {
```

to invoke the function and use its return value.

Comment: Nice catch, +1 for that

Comment: thanks. I'm sorry that because of my low reputation I can not vote up your answer.